# For a vector subspace $W$ of $\mathbb R^n$, where $n \ge 4$ and $\dim W\le n-3$, is $\mathbb R^n\setminus W $ simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $W$ be a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, where $n \ge 4$ and $\dim W\le n-3$. Then is $\mathbb R^n\setminus W $ simply connected ?

I can only see that it is path connected.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know the cellular approximation theorem? A homotopy of a loop to a point is $2$ dimensional, so will generically miss $W$ of codimension at least $3$.

Comment: Actually, it works for $n=3$ as well.

Comment: You can show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus W$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^k$ where $k = n - \dim W - 1 \geq n - (n - 3) - 1 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a complement (so $\Bbb R^n=W\oplus U$). Any Loop in $\Bbb R^n\setminus W$ can be moved to $U\setminus \{0\}$ and contracted there because  $\dim U\ge 3$.

Comment: just a query about this moving and then contracting business ... why would the original loop with the given base point be still contracted to a point ? And why is $\dim U \ge 3$ necessary ?

Comment: @users Well, it *is* the original loop that I contract. You can even fix the base point bya saying that it is wlog in $\{0\}\oplus U$. If $\dim U=2$, we have a punctured plane, where $S^1$ is not contractible

Comment: I see .. so for example $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \mathbb R$ is not contractible ?

Comment: @users $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\Bbb{R}$ is neither contractible nor simply connected. $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{\vec{0}\}$ is still not contractible, but it is simply connected.